# Azure Cloud Services, deny access to subfolder using web.config

Tags: azure, web-config, windows-server-2008, azure-web-roles

I have PHP application that I develop on my local Server 2008 dev server, I then push this to my live site on Azure Cloud Services. This all works fine. In one of my sub folders I have a `web.config` file with the following in it:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
      <security>
          <authorization>
              <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
          </authorization>
      </security>
</system.webServer>
```

If I attempt to go in to that folder, or view any file in a browser on my dev server I receive the message:

```
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
```

Which is great!..  If I attempt to go to a file in that folder on my live site, it displays the file just fine. It is completely ignoring the `web.config` file. I have connected to the running cloud instance of my live site, and can see the `web.config` file in there.

Why is it being ignored on Azure, but working fine on my dev site?

Comment: If this is a PHP site how do you intend to authenticate users to access this subfolder? If you remove anonymous access that's fine, but how do you then grant access? ServerFault has a post similar to this one: http://serverfault.com/questions/72680/iis7-how-to-block-access-with-a-web-config-file

Comment: End users don't need to access this folder directly, there does not need to be any access to this folder from the web. It is accessed by the PHP app itself which is not affected by a web.config file. Like I say the file works on my DEV server, but doesn't work on the Cloud instance on Azure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case anyone else has the same issue, you need to add a `location` element to your root web.config/web.cloud.config. It needs to be directly within the `configuration` element like so:

```
<configuration>
    .....
    .....
    <location path="--folder or file--">
        <system.web>
          <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
          </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Using the exact example gives an error. I am unable to see what the error is.